# Alterar classe com javascript ao redimensionar a tela

Tags: javascript, html, css

Preciso de um código javascript que altere a classe `menu` para a classe `responsivemenu` quando a resolução da tela for menor que `750px`.

Comment: Não podes fazer isso com CSS (media query?)

Comment: Acredito ser a melhor opção também.
Verifique se você não pode realizar essa operação diretamente no CSS.
Aqui tem um exemplo pra você dar uma estudada: http://goo.gl/LJFKRp

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Utilizando JavaScript

Note que estou verificando o tamanho dentro do bloco `window.addEventListener('resize', function() {..});`, a função será chamada toda vez em que a resolução da tela for alterada.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    //var altura = window.innerHeight;
    var largura = window.innerWidth;

    if (largura < 750) 
        document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0].className = 'responsivemenu';
});
```

## Utilizando CSS Media Query

A maneira mais simples utilizando Media Query é definir folhas de estilos especificas para cada tipo de dispositivo, para isso basta adicionar a propriedade `media` para definir para que tipo de dispositivo seu `css` será usado.
Utilize `handheld` para dispositivos de mão, celulares e outros dispositivos deste perfil. Normalmente com telas pequenas e banda limitada.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css" type="text/css" media="handheld">
```

Agora a forma que acredito ser mais correta, no seu arquivo de estilos você utilizará condicionais para definir o estilo para cada resolução que desejar.

```css
/* Estilo padrão */
menu {
  color: blue;
}

/* Estilo para resolução menor que 750 pixels */
@media screen and (max-width: 750) {
  menu {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

Dentro do bloco você irá definir o estilo específico para a resolução.

**Fonte**: [**Introdução sobre Media Queries**](http://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/)

Comment: Deveria ter sido essa a escolhida

Comment: Essa é a solução correta!

Comment: ótima resposta!
Passarei a usar mais o js sem jquery.

Comment: ótima resposta, você poderia incluir uma alternativa usando `media query`, talvez o AP desconheça este recurso e isto poderia beneficiar a ele (assim como a comunidade).

Comment: Bah @TobyMosque `media query` só sei que existe. Vou dar uma lida sobre e qualquer coisa edito a resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Há diversas maneiras de se fazer isto.

Com Jquery, por exemplo, pode ser feito assim:

```js
if ($(window).width() <= 750)
  $('.menu').removeClass('menu').addClass('responsivemenu');
  // ou
  $('.menu').attr('class','responsivemenu');
```

Há diversas formas para fazer esta operação.

Caso queira se aprofundar nesse método que apresentei, dê uma olhada em: http://goo.gl/F26YSx

Answer (score 2):

Amigão, tenta da seguinte form.

```
if(window.screen.availWidth<750){
  $('.menu').addClass('responsivemenu').removeClass('menu');
}
```

Comment: Mas preciso que isso seja executado só com resolução menor que 750px por exemplo.

Comment: O if no começo do codigo já garante que o script vai rodar apenas abaixo de 750px.
pq me deu ponto negativo? o codigo ta correto

Comment: Não dei ponto negativo @RBoschini. Dei ponto positivo, não sei quem deu ponto negativo. Inclusive usei seu código e deu certo.

Comment: Maravilha então, que bom que deu certo! precisando de ajuda é so chamar! abracos

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo tempo e gentileza, pode deixar! ;)

Comment: o `-1` possivelmente se deve ao `Amigão, usa o jquery.`, para entender veja o seguinte topico: [When is “use jQuery” not a valid answer to a JavaScript question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)

Comment: TobyMosque obrigado, vou prestar mais atenção. ;)

Comment: Não estou querendo abrir uma discussão conturbada a respeito, mas podemos ver no debate do do link(este do META) que no geral, mesmo que o AP tenha colocado Javascript no titulo, apresentar soluções com jquery ainda poderia ser válido, já que a "solução" esperada também pode ser feita com a tal lib em questão. De qualquer forma, é inegável que a resposta do Pedro seja a escolhida como "melhor resposta", que alem de simples, soluciona muito bem o problema e ainda é em JS purão. Mas convenhamos que é relativa negar a "conveniência" em usar Jquery. O que acham? [vamos ser amigáveis, please,rs]

Comment: stackoverflow brasil é mais mimimi que tecnologia, infelizmente.